# Blender Trim Sheet UV's not unwrapping

Tags: uv

[image]

The only reasoning I'm asking this is because I've searched and searched but none of the answers seem to fix my exact issue. I've used all the UV unwrap methods I found pertaining to trim sheets. They work exactly fine when I unwrap a circular mesh; however, when I try to unwrap an 'S' curved mesh I get some really bad distortion.

I am using the "follow active quads" unwrap feature. (Like I said, when I use it on a circular mesh like used in all the tutorials, it works fine. Maybe it's because of the UV space not being the same on all the faces? If so, how do I fix it?)

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the UV map you created. Using Follow active quads gives you good uv islands suitable for trim maps.

You should instead focus on how you built the model. Try to keep your quads as **square** as possible so that the distortion gets evenly distributed across all faces.

I added a wireframe to the model so that you can see how the quads gets split up into triangles and how the texture stretches over them.

[image]